# Sequential stages within parallel pipeline in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a dynamic scripted pipeline in Jenkins that has many parallel stages, but within each stage, there are multiple serial steps. I have wasted several days trying to make it work: no matter what I try, all serial substages are lumped into one stage!
Here is what I have now:

```
node () {
    stage("Parallel Demo") {
        // Canonical example to run steps in parallel

        // The map we'll store the steps in
        def stepsToRun = [:]

        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            stepsToRun["Step${i}"] = { node {
                echo "start"
                sleep 1
                echo "done"
            }}
        }
        // Actually run the steps in parallel
        // parallel takes a map as an argument
        parallel stepsToRun
    }
}
```

It gets me this beautiful parallel pipeline:

[image]

However, the moment I add a serial stage, aka:

```
node () {
    stage("Parallel Demo") {
        // Run steps in parallel

        // The map we'll store the steps in
        def stepsToRun = [:]

        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            stepsToRun["Step${i}"] = { node {
                stage("1") {
                    echo "start 1"
                    sleep 1
                    echo "done 1"
                }
                stage("2") {
                    echo "start 2"
                    sleep 1
                    echo "done 2"
                }                
            }}
        }
        // Actually run the steps in parallel
        // parallel takes a map as an argument
        parallel stepsToRun
    }
}
```

I get this ugly thing, which looks exactly the same:

[image]

To add to the offense, I see the sub-steps executed. How can I get my sub-steps show up as stages?

Also, if there is a way to have dynamic stages (sequential and parallel) with the declarative pipeline, I'm all for it. I found [you can do static sequential stages](https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/07/02/whats-new-declarative-piepline-13x-sequential-stages/) but have little clue how to make it dynamic without going back to scripted pipelines.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is how you can do something like you want

```
def stepsToRun = [:]

pipeline {
    agent none

    stages {
        stage ("Prepare Stages"){
            steps {
                script {
                    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                        stepsToRun["Step${i}"] = prepareStage("Step${i}")
                    }   
                    parallel stepsToRun
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def prepareStage(def name) {
    return {
        stage (name) {
            stage("1") {
                echo "start 1"
                sleep 1
                echo "done 1"
            }
            stage("2") {
                echo "start 2"
                sleep 1
                echo "done 2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Any way to make `prepareStage` be dynamic, i.e. run 3 stages in a loop?

Comment: Looks like you cannot restart individual stage, only all "My Stages"

Comment: That's because you can do it for top stages only [https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/running-pipelines/#restart-from-a-stage]

Comment: Beware that, AFAIU, none of the stages has an allocated node. So you might need to enclse the stages in `node{}`.