# Jenkins parallel stages - enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: jenkins, npm, parallel-processing, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am having a problem running some stages in parallel across different agents/nodes in Jenkins.  I am creating stages dynamically from a list of available agents with the following code:

```java
// Create empty collection to store parallel stages:
def parallelStages = [:]

// Define list of agents to be used for cypress parallel stages:
agents = [
    "agent1",
    "agent2", 
    ...
]

// Add as many parallel stages as defined in agents list:
agents.eachWithIndex { label, index ->
    parallelStages["Parallel Stage ${index + 1}"] = {
        stage("Parallel Stage ${index + 1}") { 
            node(label) {
                sh 'npm install --silent'
                sh 'npm start & npx wait-on http://localhost:3000'
                sh "npm run another_command"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I'm using these stages in a parallel block:

```java
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'agent1'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('first-non-parallel-stage'){
            steps {
                sh 'npm install --silent'
                sh 'npm run lint'
                sh 'npm run build'
                sh "npm run storybook:build"
                sh 'npm run test -- --watchAll=false'
            }
        }
        stage ('Parallel stuff'){
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel parallelStages
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is working.  However, for the stage on agent1, I get the following errors in the Jenkins log:

```
+ npx wait-on http://localhost:3000
+ npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/vine/workspace/tend-multibranch_jenkins-testing@3/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vine/workspace/tend-multibranch_jenkins-testing@3/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Some details that might be pertinent, but I'm not sure:

- Prior to running the parallel stage, you can see I'm running a `first-non-parallel-stage`, *on the agent that is having problems* - could that be related?  I don't have problems in `first-non-parallel-stage`, just in the parallel block on that agent.  Shouldn't I be able to reuse agent1 in my parallel block after `first-non-parallel-stage` is done?
- I don't get this issue when I use a repetetive verbose parallel block, i.e. instead of creating a function that populates a collection with `stage` blocks, I write them out by hand, like this:

```java
parallel {
   stage { ...stage_code }
   stage { ...stage_code }
   stage { ...stage_code }
}
```

But obviously this is verbose and doesn't lend to adding more nodes easily.

Why might this be happening?

Comment: This error tends to happen when you already have a `package-lock.json` before calling `npm install`, which is the case on your `agent1`. try to first delete the `package-lock.json` (if it exists) In the parallel code block or after the non-parallel stage.

Comment: Would it be overkill to do a `deleteDir()` at the beginning of each stage?  Or, if I run ` sh "rm package-lock.json"`, will the agent already be in correct location in the file tree to find it?

Comment: Both options should do the job

Comment: Unfortunately neither one is helping.  I've tried removing package-lock.json, I've tried `deleteDir()` before or after each stage, I've tried `cleanWs()`...nothing seems to be working.  What's worse now is that the problem is happening on *more* nodes, not just the one.  I'm not sure what I might be doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to comments from Noam Hemler and Altaf, I figured this out.

The crucial issue was that npm could indeed not find my project.  What was being missed in some of the comments is the workspace should be cleaned before or after running the job, but the git repo scm must also be checked out fresh before trying to run any npm commands.  I created this `setup` function:

```java
def setup(){
    // clean workspace and do a fresh checkout
    deleteDir()
    git credentialsId: 'id', url: 'url'
    sh 'git checkout ' + env.Branch_Name
}
```

And now at the start of each stage:

```java
// Add as many parallel stages as defined in agents list:
agents.eachWithIndex { label, index ->
    parallelStages["Parallel Stage ${index + 1}"] = {
        stage("Parallel Stage ${index + 1}") { 
            node(label) {
                setup()
                sh 'npm install --silent'
                sh 'npm start & npx wait-on http://localhost:3000'
                sh "npm run another_command"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm using the `setup` function before any steps on any other agent too, so when a stage starts, it always cleans the space, pulls a fresh copy of the code, and begins from there.  Seems to be working consistently.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs at the `npm` side as it is not able to find the file.May be would be a good idea to add `npm init` which creates the `package.json` file or delete the `package-lock.json` file after the non-parallel stage execution is done, so that when you enter the parallel block everything is clean.
 More details about this is available here :  [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531633/npm-warn-enoent-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-open-c-users-nuwanst-packag)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help...I don't want to run `npm init`...I should already *be* in an npm package project that I pulled from my scm, I shouldn't have to init one.  As I mentioned in the other comments, removing package-lock.json is not working either.  I'm not sure why this is happening, and inconsistently.